# ml5.js tf.js featureExtractor addImage memory leak WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost

Tags: memory, webgl, tensorflow.js, ml5.js

images resolution is 100x100, on image ~900 (based on memory load) screen become black and error appear:
**Couldn't parse line number in error:**
**WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost**

[image: WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
        /* ===
      ml5 Memory Leak Example
      === */

      //init
      base64Images = [  "data:image/png;base64,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"
      ];

      curImg = 0;
      imgCount = 1000;

      //ml5
      featureExtractor = ml5.featureExtractor("MobileNet", function () {
        classifier = featureExtractor.classification();

        addSamplesEach();
      });

      //add samples loop
      function addSamplesEach() {
        if (curImg >= imgCount) {
          return;
        }

        let img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

        img.onload = function () {
          console.log('added...')

          const img = this;

          classifier.addImage(img, "label", function () {
            curImg++;
            addSamplesEach();
          });
        };

        img.src = base64Images[0];
        img = null;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the only working solution I found is turn off — **Use hardware acceleration when available** in Chrome

**ml5.tf.setBackend("cpu");** — also works in same way

another useful thing was `ml5.tf.ENV.set('WEBGL_PACK', false);` — adding images become really fast, but memory leak still persist and this didn't solved issue :(

it looks like problem somewhere inside [**imageUtilities.js**](https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-library/blob/main/src/utils/imageUtilities.js)

```
function imgToTensor(input, size = null) {
  return tf.tidy(() => {
    let img = tf.browser.fromPixels(input);
    if (size) {
      img = tf.image.resizeBilinear(img, size);
    }
    const croppedImage = cropImage(img);
    const batchedImage = croppedImage.expandDims(0);
    return batchedImage.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(127)).sub(tf.scalar(1));
  });
}
```

as I understand from this **tf.tidy** should do all good memory cleaning things in background, but it didn't...

maybe someone know how to force to clean memory without loosing progress on adding data to model?